# React Native UI-Kitten: Will running `npx react-native link` to link fonts affect other native modules?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm using UI Kitten with my latest React Native app, and in [this section](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/branding) of the docs it says `Run npx react-native link from the project root to link fonts with the native side`. I haven't used `npx react-native link` in a long time because of autolinking. So my question is: will running `npx react-native link` affect any of my native modules or anything else in the app in a way that I should know about (other than the desired linking of fonts here)?

Comment: running react-native link will link the assets of your app, it should not affect any native modules. However just for precautionary measure, just create a backup of your project

Comment: What does it mean to link the assets of my project, and how do we know that this wouldn't affect native modules? The reason I assumed it affected native modules is that in the past I would do `npm add <modules>` followed by `npm link <module>` which would link the module.